# doubleBinding has no effect

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I'm taking my first experiment with TornadoFX and ran into a problem I don't understand.

I have an object `Wind`:

```
enum class Direction(val displayName: String, val abbrevation: String, val deltaX: Int, val deltaY: Int) {

    NORTH("Észak", "É", 0, -1),
    NORTH_EAST("Északkelet", "ÉK", 1, -1),
    EAST("Kelet", "K", 1, 0),
    SOUTH_EAST("Délkelet", "DK", 1, 1),
    SOUTH("Dél", "D", 0, 1),
    SOUTH_WEST("Délnyugat", "DNy", -1, 1),
    WEST("Nyugat", "Ny", -1, 0),
    NORTH_WEST("Északnyugat", "ÉNy", -1, -1);

    val diagonal: Boolean = deltaX != 0 && deltaY != 0
    val degree: Double = ordinal * 45.0

    fun turnClockwise(eighth: Int = 1) = values()[(ordinal + eighth) umod 8]
    fun turnCounterClockwise(eighth: Int = 1) = values()[(ordinal - eighth) umod 8]
    fun turn(eighth: Int = 1) = if (eighth < 0) turnCounterClockwise(eighth.absoluteValue) else turnClockwise(eighth)

    infix operator fun plus(eighth: Int) = turn(eighth)
    infix operator fun minus(eighth: Int) = turn(-eighth)

    infix operator fun minus(other: Direction) = (ordinal - other.ordinal) umod 8
}

object Wind {

    val directionProperty = SimpleObjectProperty<Direction>(Direction.NORTH)
    var direction: Direction
        get() = directionProperty.value
        set(value) {
            println("SET WIND: $value")
            directionProperty.value = value
        }
}
```

I would like to bound a rotation transformation to the setting of wind direction.

When I use the old, JavaFX style, it works:

```
rot.angleProperty().bind(
    createDoubleBinding(
        Callable { 
            println("Direction: ${Wind.direction}");       
            Wind.directionProperty.value.degree * 45 
        }, 
        Wind.directionProperty))
```

When I try to use the more elegant, Kotlin-style version, it doesn't bind:

```
rot.angleProperty().doubleBinding(rot.angleProperty() ) {
    println("Direction: ${Wind.direction}")
    Wind.directionProperty.value.degree * 45
}
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `doubleBinding()` function creates a `Binding`, but it does not bind it to anything.

In fact, we have two ways to create this binding:

1. `doubleBinding(someProperty) { ... }`. The operates on the property (this) and expects you to return a Double. It is not nullable.
2. `someProperty.doubleBinding() { ... }` receives the value as a parameter and expects you to return a Double. The parameter is nullable, so you need to account for that

That leaves you with two options:

```
rot.angleProperty().bind(doubleBinding(Wind.directionProperty) {
    value.degree * 45
})
```

Or

```
rot.angleProperty().bind(Wind.directionProperty.doubleBinding {
    it?.degree ?: 0.0 * 45 
})
```

Which one you choose is mostly a matter of taste, though one will be more natural than the other in some cases.